# How do I eliminate the repetition in this template helper?

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a Meteor Handlebars template helper that is representative of most of my template helpers as shown below.

```
# Address Form Controls Template
Template.AddressFormControls.helpers
    address1: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building?.address?.address1

    address2: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building.address.address2

    city: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building.address.city

    state: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building.address.state

    zip_code: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building.address.zip_code

    main: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building?.phone?.main

    fax: () ->
        if typeof Session.get('edit-building') is 'string'
            building = Buildings.findOne(Session.get('edit-building'))
            return building?.phone?.fax
```

You will notice that every helper contains an `if` statement to see if the Session variable is a string.  If it's a string, then it should be an ID that can be used to perform the search for the needed object.

It seems like such a waste to have that repeated throughout a project for the various collections that one uses.

How can I DRY this up?

Help me Obiwan you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten it with something like

js:

```
main:function() {
    building = Buildings.findOne({_id:Session.get('edit-building')}) 
    return building && building.phone && building.phone.main;
}
```

coffee:

```
main: () ->
    building = Buildings.findOne(_id: Session.get("edit-building"))
    building and building.phone and building.phone.main
```

The key difference being explicitly saying you want the `_id` to match. So in the case the `Session` variable for `edit-building` doesn't exist, isn't a string or doesn't match any records nothing is returned.

Just this might shorten your code a lot too:

```
building: () ->
    Buildings.findOne(_id: Session.get("edit-building"))
```

Then in your html (in the AddressFormControls template) you could do:

```
{{#if building}}
    Phone: {{building.phone.main}}
    Fax: {{building.phone.fax}}
    ....
{{/if}}
```

Comment: In your main function returning `var and anotherVar and otherVar` will return a `true` or `false` value not actual values.  That's not what I am looking for.  I need the actual value returned as the sample code does.

Comment: Why would it return a true or false? Isn't `and` translated to `&&`? In which case the last statement is taken as the final value in javascript. I.e `1 && 2 && 3 && 4 === 4`